# Adding string values of hashmap to JComboBox

Tags: java

I am a Java newbie and I would like to get all the values from different class that uses hashmap to populate my JComboBox

```
 public class StockData {

private static class Item {

    Item(String n, double p, int q) {
        name = n;
        price = p;
        quantity = q;
    }

    // get methods
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    // instance variables 
    private final String name;
    private final double price;
    private int quantity;
}

// with a Map you use put to insert a key, value pair 
// and get(key) to retrieve the value associated with a key
// You don't need to understand how this works!
private final static Map<String, Item> stock = new HashMap();

static {
    // if you want to have extra stock items, put them in here
    // use the same style - keys should be Strings
    stock.put("00", new Item("Bath towel", 5.50, 10));
    stock.put("11", new Item("Plebney light", 20.00, 5));
    stock.put("22", new Item("Gorilla suit", 30.00, 7));
    stock.put("33", new Item("Whizz games console", 50.00, 8));
    stock.put("44", new Item("Oven", 200.00, 4));
}
public static Map<String, Item> getStock() {
    return stock;
   }
public static String getName(String key) {
    Item item = stock.get(key);
    if (item == null) {
        return null; // null means no such item
    } else {
        return item.getName();
    }
}
}
```

and I would like to put all those values like Bath towel, Plebney light etc in my JCombobox.

```
  package stock;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PurchaseItem extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   // StockData ss = new StockData();
       JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(stock.values().stream().map(Item::getName).toArray(String[]::new));
JComboBox b = new JComboBox();
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question or problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Item object has a getName function you could write this:

```
    JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(
        stock.values().stream()
        .map(Item::getName)
        .toArray(String[]::new)
    );
```

I think the best way to understand the syntax is for you to go and read the javadoc of the methods invoked. Still a small explanation .values() returns a set of all the values in the stock map then stream as the documentation says returns a sequential stream with the collection as the source then map calles the getName() function (I assume you have: public String getName()) for each object in the stream and then you turn all the strings you have into a array of strings. By result it is the same as:

```
    JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>();
        for(Item item:stock.values()){
            box.addItem(item.getName());
        }
```

EDIT:

If the stock variable is in a different class then PurchaseItem than PurchaseItem can't see it. You can make it exposed either by changing the privacy or by making a get function for it:

```
   public static Map<String, Item> getStock() {
    return stock;
   }
```

Since for the function i originaly wrote you you need the vlaues you could make a getter for the vlaue set like this:

```
public static Collection<Item> getStock() {
    return stock.values();
}
```

and then modifie the code like this:

```
JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(
        NameOfTheClassWhichContainsStock.getStock().stream()
        .map(Item::getName)
        .toArray(String[]::new)
);
```

EDIT2:
Your Item class is private so it is not visible outside of the StockData class that is why it can't be found. If you change the Item class to public and import the StockData  in the PurchaseItem class then you can write:

```
JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(StockData.getStock()
    .values()
    .stream()
    .map(StockData.Item::getName)
    .toArray(String[]::new)
);
```

EDIT3: state on my pc:

```
package stockdata;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StockData {

public static class Item {

    Item(String n, double p, int q) {
        name = n;
        price = p;
        quantity = q;
    }

    // get methods
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    // instance variables
    private final String name;
    private final double price;
    private int quantity;
}

// with a Map you use put to insert a key, value pair
// and get(key) to retrieve the value associated with a key
// You don't need to understand how this works!
private final static Map<String, Item> stock = new HashMap<>();

static {
    // if you want to have extra stock items, put them in here
    // use the same style - keys should be Strings
    stock.put("00", new Item("Bath towel", 5.50, 10));
    stock.put("11", new Item("Plebney light", 20.00, 5));
    stock.put("22", new Item("Gorilla suit", 30.00, 7));
    stock.put("33", new Item("Whizz games console", 50.00, 8));
    stock.put("44", new Item("Oven", 200.00, 4));
}

public static Map<String, Item> getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public static String getName(String key) {
    Item item = stock.get(key);
    if (item == null) {
        return null; // null means no such item
    } else {
        return item.getName();
    }
}
}
```

//=================================================================

```
package stockdata;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import stockdata.StockData;

public class PurchaseItem extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    // StockData ss = new StockData();
    JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(StockData.getStock().values().stream().map(StockData.Item::getName).toArray(String[]::new));
    JComboBox b = new JComboBox();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

EDIT4:

```
public double getPriceForName(String itemName){

    return StockData.getStock()
            .values()
            .stream()
            .filter(item->item.getName().equals(itemName))//filter only those whit the given name
            .mapToDouble(StockData.Item::getPrice)//get item price
            .findFirst()//Item name should be unique then it is ok to do this
            .getAsDouble();//if there is no item with the given name this will throw a NoSuchElementException
}

public int getQuantityForName(String itemName){

    return StockData.getStock()
            .values()
            .stream()
            .filter(item->item.getName().equals(itemName))//filter only those whit the given name
            .mapToInt(StockData.Item::getQuantity)//get item quantity
            .findFirst()//Item name should be unique then it is ok to do this
            .getAsInt();//if there is no item with the given name this will throw a NoSuchElementException
}
```

Comment: JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<>(StockData.values().stream().map(Item::getName).toArray(String[]::new));
Alright slowly starting to understand that still get an error with values() is it internal java function or do I have to make that function?  and Item is highlighted as well looking into it

Comment: values() is a function of the Map interface. You (@Higeath) can find the functions of the Map interface here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html.

Comment: If you post more of your code I can help you find the problem.

Comment: then I would assume it doesn't work because  private final static Map<String, Item> stock = new HashMap(); the whole map is private

Comment: @Higeath see the edit and feel free to ask questions If you need further help.

Comment: alright so I used getter using the first method with return stock and that went through but it still highlights Item as variable that doesn't exist

Comment: Is your Item getName() method static? If it is it should not be.
Could you add your Item class?

Comment: Also you can edit the code in the answer to the current version.

Comment: I've just added pretty much the whole code for that bit

Comment: One last thing if you wouldn't mind is there an easy way to get the price of the item depending on which item was chosen via the dropdown and the quantity?

Comment: Is there a simpler way to have a function just in SotckData class? so I could use it later on in multiple classes and it would make sense to put it there

Comment: You can make both functions static and put them in StockData and it is ok to put them there. You have some String as a key in your map. As the code is at the moment it would make more sense if that was the item name.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to put Item into JComboBox and override the item toString function to return the item name. It would say the name in the ComboBox but you would have the whole item internally in the code.